# Plotting a cropped background image on a matplotlib graph

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to plot a simple line plot and insert a background image to a plot.

An example pic (with cat.jpg and dog.jpd):

[image: I have two background images, I'd like to use; cat.jpg and dog.jpg]

At the moment I have a code that plots the line (from a pandas dataframe) and places the images into figure. However the images and the line plot do not 'interact' at all.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,10))
cat = np.array(Image.open('cat.jpg'))
dog = np.array(Image.open('dog.jpg'))
ax.imshow(cat, extent=[0, 10, 0, 18], aspect='auto',   cmap='gray',alpha=0.75)
ax.imshow(dog, extent=[10, 20, 0, 18], aspect='auto', cmap='gray',alpha=0.75)

ax.plot(df['Series'],color='#3cb8fb',alpha=0.95,linewidth=3.0)

plt.show()
```

Comment: What kind of interaction are you expecting?

Comment: I meant that I'd like to crop the cat and dog images so that they would go in line with the line plot (like in the example picture).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`plt.fill_between`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between) to create a polygon that covers the area between the origin and the line, then use the [`.set_clip_path`](http://matplotlib.org/api/artist_api.html?highlight=set_clip_path#matplotlib.artist.Artist.set_clip_path) method of each image object to display only the part of the image that falls within the polygon.

For example:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.misc import lena

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)

x = np.linspace(0, 1, 10)
y = np.random.rand(10)
image = ax.imshow(lena(), cmap=plt.cm.gray, extent=[0, 1, 0, 1])
line = ax.plot(x, y, '-r', lw=2)

# invisible clipping polygon
poly = ax.fill_between(x, 0, y, visible=False)
clip = poly.get_paths()[0]

# you will need to do this separately for each of the images in your plot
image.set_clip_path(clip, transform=ax.transData)

plt.show()
```

[image]