# Add a background image to matplotlib plot / gif

Tags: python, matplotlib, gif

I have a task that calls a plot numerous times and creates a gif from the results (see below for a reproducible example).

My question is: I would like to add a background image to this gif. My guess is, I would have to add it somewhere in the loop, before appending.

What I found so far, although hilarious did not really relate to my question:

[Plotting a cropped background image on a matplotlib graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34495817/plotting-a-cropped-background-image-on-a-matplotlib-graph)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib.animation import PillowWriter
import time

rng = np.random.default_rng()
fig = plt.figure(figsize=[10, 9])

ims = []
for i in range(200):
    df = pd.DataFrame(rng.integers(0, 100, size=(100, 2)), columns=list('xy'))
    x = df["x"]
    y = df["y"]
    im = plt.plot(x, y, "b.")
    ims.append(im)
    print(i)
    
    
    

ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, ims, interval=500, blit=True,
                                repeat_delay=1000)

writer = PillowWriter(fps=2)
ani.save("demo2.gif", writer=writer)
```

sources:

[How to create a DataFrame of random integers with Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32752292/how-to-create-a-dataframe-of-random-integers-with-pandas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a lot of experience with this, but I was able to display the image I called beforehand with `plt.imshow()`. The `demo.gif` could not be uploaded due to file size limitations. Sorry, the image used in the sample is not good. Sorry.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib.animation import PillowWriter
import time
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

rng = np.random.default_rng()
fig = plt.figure(figsize=[10, 9])

img = mpimg.imread('lena_thumbnail_center_square.jpg')

ims = []
for i in range(200):
    df = pd.DataFrame(rng.integers(0, 100, size=(100, 2)), columns=list('xy'))
    x = df["x"]
    y = df["y"]
    im = plt.plot(x, y, "b.")
    ims.append(im)
#     print(i)   

ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, ims, interval=500, blit=True,
                                repeat_delay=1000)
plt.imshow(img)

writer = PillowWriter(fps=2)
ani.save("demo2.gif", writer=writer)
```

[image]

Comment: no need to apologize! solution works fine! problem now: the underlying picture is way too big to fit my points, any ideas for that?

Comment: I'm not sure about the size of the image, so I can't say for sure, but does `plt.figure(figsize((10,9), dpi=350)` solve the problem?

Comment: sorry, I think I worded it badly: the underlying image has dimensions of say 1000x2000, yet my datapoints are in the range of 0-100. I just needed to fit my image to that size beforehand and it worked :)