# Add image to background of plot with Seaborn & Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to create a Control Variability Grid Analysis in Python. This analysis requires plotting min and max blood glucose values (in this case, my own) per day on a scatterplot, with a background image that helps classify the overall glucose control. See [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2769756/).

I have found other threads that address this question, but I cannot seem to get it to work for my application. I need the axes to be a specific range, and I think that is interfering with the image. The code I have tried so far, based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15160123/adding-a-background-image-to-a-plot-with-known-corner-coordinates) page and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63371265/add-a-background-image-to-matplotlib-plot-gif) page, is as follows:

```
img = plt.imread('CVGA.png')
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (12,6))
sns.scatterplot(data=min_max_day,x=min_max_day['Glucose Value (mg/dL)']['amin'],
            y=min_max_day['Glucose Value (mg/dL)']['amax'], zorder=1)
plt.xlim(110,40)
plt.ylim(110,400)
ax.imshow(img);
```

And the output looks like this:

[image: Failed output]

With the line "ax.imshow(img)" removed, the output looks like this:

[image: Correct graph without background image]

Additional details:

- the image I'm using is 1200x1200:

[image: this]

- Maybe there is a problem with the fact that the scale I'm using isn't a perfect square? Not sure if that makes sense, but clearly 110 to 400 on the Y axis and 100 to 40 on the X axis would not make a perfect square? I am unsure what to do about that.

Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use the `extent` parameter as shown in [Change values on matplotlib imshow() graph axis](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18696122/7758804), but you must also use `aspect='auto'` and set `figsize = (12, 12)` (or `(6, 6)`, etc.).

  - See all parameters at [`matplotlib.pyplot.imshow`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html)
- `sns.scatterplot` from the OP is commented out because no data was provided.
- **Tested in `python 3.8`, `matplotlib 3.4.2`, and `seaborn 0.11.1`**

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np  # sample data

img = plt.imread('CVGA.png')
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 6))
# sns.scatterplot(data=min_max_day, x=min_max_day['Glucose Value (mg/dL)']['amin'], y=min_max_day['Glucose Value (mg/dL)']['amax'], zorder=1)

sns.scatterplot(x=np.linspace(110, 41, 10), y=np.linspace(110, 401, 10), ax=ax)
plt.xlim(110, 40)
plt.ylim(110, 400)

ax.imshow(img, extent=[110, 40, 110, 400], aspect='auto')
```

[image]

Comment: THANK YOU so much. 'aspect=auto' was what I was missing. You are the best!

Comment: @walker967 You're welcome. Glad that works for you.